# TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' while being assigned on the previous line

Tags: typescript, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I've been looking at the questions and answers regarding this TypeScript error but none of them are the same as the problem as the one I will describe here as far as I know.

The exact error I get is: `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.` where `self.session` had a red squiggly underline

```js
  self.session = {}
  self.session.ready = true
```

This is the "type" of session:

```js
export const AuthStore = BaseMixin.named('AuthStore')
  .props({
    session: types.maybe(SessionData)
  })
```

You would think that it's pretty clear the `session` is initialized at this moment but still TypeScript it might now be. I tried wrapping it in an "if" statement to check if `self` is initialized but that didn't fix it.

Previously we fixed it using: `self.session!.ready = true` but that's of course a workaround and not a proper fix.

I think I know TypeScript but TypeScript likes to prove me wrong often.

*We're using TypeScript version `4.2.4`*

Here's a link to codesandbox where I reproduced the same issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-ek721c?file=/index.ts

**update** (The screenshot is only to show where TypeScript is adding the red underline, I thought this might help since it doesn't normally underline the object and supposed undefined property If I remember correctly)

[image: ts underline]

Comment: If you would consider it exceptional for `self` to be undefined here, I'd do a check like this: `if (self.session === undefined) { throw new Error("Unexpected error initializing session"); }` to satisfy typescript. (with the added benefit that you can potentially explain why this would be an error if it does happen)

Comment: Though I will say, I don't know what `types.maybe` is. Is that what could be introducing the nullability? Might be unrelated, but is a curious thing.

Comment: Please provide a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now if I look at that I get [unrelated errors](https://tsplay.dev/mx8aGm) so it's not reproducible.  Also, [please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite I am aware of that and I didn't, I posted the error message in plain text in my question. The image is there to visualize the red underline since I am not sure if it normally should only add the line to the property. So I thought this might help someone to identify the issue. 

But thanks for checking!

Comment: The image is unnecessary. The text representation of the error is sufficient. Images should be used only when there is no other way to demonstrate an issue, which is clearly not the case when you can post the error message as text. The many reasons NOT to post images is in the link I provided.

Comment: @KenWhite I editted my question with further explanation, I see you have far more experience on the platform than I do so please let me know if you think this is ok or should be removed. I personally think it helps since the highlighting of an undefined property normally looks different

Comment: @jcalz you are right, here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-ek721c?file=/index.ts

Comment: @JohnPaulR Well, that indeed fixed my issue. Thanks for that. I personally don't like adding code to satisfy typescript when the code is already correctly typed. I would like to understand what's causing this issue. I added a link to codesandbox, do you mind looking at it? Maybe you might see what the issue actually is

Comment: Please include the [mre] as plain text in the question itself; an external link is a nice supplement but it's not sufficient by itself.  Also, the example isn't really self-contained, as it depends on whatever mobx-state-tree is.  If you can't reproduce the problem without a third party library then maybe you should tag the question with `mobx-state-tree` so that people who know about it (not me!) can take a look.

Comment: So [here](//tsplay.dev/mMBX1W) is what I would consider a [mre] that demonstrates what you're seeing (with the line that would fix your issue commented out).  `JSON.parse()`'s return type is `any`, so the compiler has absolutely no idea what you've assigned to `self.session`.  It could be anything including `undefined` (even though `undefined` actually cannot come out of `JSON.parse()`, but `any` doesn't capture that info.  But `null` *can* come out of it, so it's kind of a wash).

Comment: So on the next line the compiler cannot verify that it's defined. You can fix with a type assertion on the `JSON.parse()` output to specify what type you expect it will be.  If this all addresses your needs I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining (but please do put a plain-text minimal example in the question, possibly the one from my link).   If not, what am I missing?  (Pls mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply).

Comment: @jcalz You gave me all the info I needed to understand this, that's all there is. It appears not to be related to mobx or any library but just the way typescript deals with JSON.parse. Thank a lot! Do you think I should delete the question? It may be to vague for others to help them out

Comment: I think if you [edit] the question so that it has the `Problem` part of [this code example](https://tsplay.dev/mMBX1W) in it and ask how to fix it, I could write up the answer explaining.  I think the basic question is good and useful to keep around.  If you don't have time I could do the editing if you want

Comment: Isn't volatile state supposed to be local? https://mobx-state-tree.js.org/concepts/volatiles#modelvolatile

Comment: @user16967562 I think this is unrelated, right? Or is it just something you noticed and wanted to point out?